# Is a Kotlin Liferay portlet possible?

Tags: java, liferay, portlet, kotlin

As I couldn't find any example for this I am wondering if it is possible to create a Liferay Portlet which uses (pure) Kotlin instead of traditional Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin targets the JVM - so technically: Yes.

Will anybody be able to help you doing so, share their findings: Probably not.

Do common build processes exist? Not that I know.

And it'll probably make a difference if you write a portlet for Liferay 6.2 or for 7 - unless you're aiming at just the standard JSR286 portlet.

This is a little bit like PHP-portlets in a Java Portal. It can be done, but once you run into the first issue, you'll have a hard time finding anyone to help you identify (or fix) the problem.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to write portlets in Kotlin with just a little bit of tweaking.

Download the latest version of kotlin library:
https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/v1.0.4

Unzip and copy the whole content of lib folder into the Liferay SDK lib folder. So at the end you should have something like /path-to-liferay-sdk/lib/kotlin-*.jar

Open build-comon.xml file in Liferay SDK directory and search for ***javac*** tag (it's around line 900).

Add the following line before the javac tag:

```
<typedef resource="org/jetbrains/kotlin/ant/antlib.xml" classpath="${sdk.dir}/lib/kotlin-ant.jar"/>
```

and also insert `<withKotlin/>` inside the javac tag:

```
<typedef resource="org/jetbrains/kotlin/ant/antlib.xml" classpath="${sdk.dir}/lib/kotlin-ant.jar"/>
<javac
  classpathref="@{javac.classpathref}"
  compiler="${javac.compiler}"
  debug="${javac.debug}"
  deprecation="${javac.deprecation}"
  destdir="@{javac.destdir}"
  encoding="${javac.encoding}"
  includeAntRuntime="false"
  nowarn="${javac.nowarn}"
  source="${javac.source}"
  srcdir="@{javac.srcdir}"
  target="${javac.target}">
 <withKotlin/>
</javac>
```

That's it. If you run `ant deploy` ant will compile *.kt files together with *.java for you. Now, if you are using Intellij IDEA you can add a Kotlin file into your project. The IDE will configure the project for you. It will also add 3 files (kotlin-reflect.jar, kotlin-runtime.jar, kotlin-runtime-sources.jar) into the newly created lib folder. However, you need to copy these files into the docroot/WEB-INF/lib folder to make it available.

I posted a blog about it here: http://www.lims.io/blog/liferay-portlets-in-kotlin